# Scrapy - get map information

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, maps

I'm trying to scrap the information of "5 Postos de abastecimento" from the section "Mapa" on https://www.imovirtual.com/anuncio/moradia-no-alto-da-ajuda-para-reconstrucao-ID10VFW.html#46747dcb9d using Scrapy.

When I look at the web site in chrome the map section appears and I can inspect the html in developer tools and find the information on the **div class style__place___1StFN**.

But when I try to find this div class in scrapy shell it wont find anything:

```
response.css('div.style__place___1StFN ')
```

I looked at the network in developer tools and try to find any other GEt / POST response that has this information but wasn't able to find it.

Any suggestion?

Thank you